# I want to build a custom angularjs Unique Value Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to build a directive that checks for duplicate username. So I have created an index.html file and an `uniqueId` directive. Now in the directive I am not able to do `ngModel.setValidity()`. It is getting `undefined`.

Also I am fetching data from a local json file username.json.

When I console log `console.log(ngModel.$setValidity('unique', unique))` I get `undefined`.

I have created a plunk for the code::

https://embed.plnkr.co/XTPf9PjiMn9if5Y0DaHt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the users present in JSON. And, if your `currentValue` matches any of those, you need to set it as invalid using `$setValidity`. Like this:

```
dataService.getUsers().then(function(currentusers) {
    console.log(currentusers)
      //Ensure value that being checked hasn't changed
      //since the Ajax call was made
    if (currentValue == element.val()) {
      currentusers.forEach(function(user) {
        if (currentValue === user.property) {
          ngModel.$setValidity('unique', false)
        }
      });
    }
  }, function() {
    //Probably want a more robust way to handle an error
    //For this demo we'll set unique to true though
    ngModel.$setValidity('unique', true);
  });
});
```

Also, your service was getting the JSON every time. Alternatively, you can store your JSON response in a variable inside your angular service (which is a singleton) so it's faster than before. Like this,

```
dataFactory.getUsers = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer()
  if (angular.isDefined(savedResults)) {
    deferred.resolve(savedResults.data);
    return deferred.promise;
  } else {
    return $http.get(serviceBase).then(
      function(results) {
        savedResults = results
        return results.data;
      });
  }
};
```

Here, we return a resolved promise if data is already available. It will get the JSON for the first time and will use from within.

[**working plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/EJOWJ9KHnQlfP8gEgVte?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

please check [plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lh1qiV3s7V2kil6AmzKk?p=preview)

If you type `nitesh@gmail.com`, it will display email already in use.
If you type `nitesh@gmail.com1`, it won't show error message.
I have changed condition.

Comment: No Mansi, It is not showing the message in plunker. What condition have you changed.

Comment: Don't know why it is not working for you. I changed this :
`dataService.checkUniqueValue(keyProperty.key, keyProperty.property, currentValue)
            .then(function(unique) {
              if (unique == element.val()) {     
                ngModel.$setValidity('unique', false);
              } else {
                ngModel.$setValidity('unique', true);
              }
            }, function() {
              ngModel.$setValidity('unique', true);
            });`

Comment: Got it we need to iterate over each value before setting to true or false. Thanks for your time.